# Survey for Local Navigation

Tags: navigation, motion-planning

I was wondering if there was a good book or paper that surveys current techniques in local navigation? The earliest one I could find was from 2005 and I was hoping to find something more recent.

I have worked with certain approaches such as the dynamic window approach and the velocity obstacles approach. I'm hoping for some book or paper to give me a broader perspective to the problem of local navigation which I believe has been fairly robustly solved by a number of autonomous driving companies.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* pract, but I'm afraid that this really isn't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Alright, so where do I ask this kind of question?

Comment: Since this is asking for opinions rather than solutions, its the sort of thing forums are good for. For stack exchange you are better off asking about specific problems that you are having with specific approaches. If you frame your question as a problem in search of a solution, we are much more likely to be able to help you here.